# How to toggle "include in RSS" through SoundCloud API

Tags: soundcloud

With SoundCloud for podcasters it's possible to add uploads to a RSS feed:
http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1209292-can-i-podcast-with-soundcloud-

I would like to add podcast episodes through the API, using /tracks endpoint like so:
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks

How do I toggle "include in RSS" when I upload a track through API?

Comment: Well, nothing. There aren't any properties in documentation for it.
SoundCloud for podcasters is still in beta, from what I can gather, so I was wondering if they have added this to the API in an undocumented way.
SoundCloud help said, that for technical questions I should go to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Then ask their support and [read how to post questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm asking their support as per these instructions: https://developers.soundcloud.com/support

I don't believe my question violates any StackOverflow question guidelines

Answer (score 1):

the option is not documented, but what your looking for is 'feedable' which should have a true or false value.